# C++20 auto template parameter not working as expected (GCC bug?)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++20, compile-time

I'm trying to create a library that works with polynomial functions at compile time in C++. I will let a link to an instance of compiler explorer to take a look (https://godbolt.org/z/6xo9E9csW).

In the main function I made 4 operations, 3 of them are a subtraction of 4 polynomial functions multiplication and the last operation is an addition of 2 polynomials. The problem is that the result of these operations is really weird. If you try to comment first 3 lines of code from main, you'll see that the addition is done correctly. If you uncomment those operations, the compiler gives a strange result and I don't know if it's a bug in my code or it's a GCC bug.

Strangely, if all coefficients of the polynomial functions are integer numbers, all operations are done correctly.

P.S.: Coefficients from std::array mCoeffs are in order mCoeffs[0] = a<sub>n</sub>, mCoeffs[1] = a<sub>n-1</sub>, all the way up to mCoeffs[n] = a<sub>0</sub>, where n is the degree of the polynomial, and a<sub>n</sub> corresponds to x<sup>n</sup> term.

If you can help, please let me know. Thank you!

Andrei

Comment: Please, try to reduce the example first.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre]. Do you have any reason to believe that this is a GCC bug? Does GCC's output not match up with what the standard says it should be?

Comment: supposed this is a compiler bug and you wanted to file a bug report, then you would also be required to prepare a small example that exhibits the problem. Also you should explicitly state what is expected and actual output of the code. "really weird" does not explain whats wrong with it

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to reduce the code, now only the functions add, sub and mult are there. I clean the main function and only a minimal example is shown. If you run the code with TYPE double, addition is wrong, if TYPE is int, the addition is correct. Also, if you comment sub_multiplies and TYPE is double, the addition is correct. Here is the new compiler explorer link. (https://godbolt.org/z/G6qGxWxzM)

Comment: @Brian In clang this works as expected. Can you explain me why, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
constexpr Polynomial() : mCoeffs{ ArithmeticType{} } {}
```

Does not works as you intented, it does not fill all the array with zeros, only the first position, replace it by :

```
constexpr Polynomial() {  mCoeffs.fill( ArithmeticType{0} ); }
```

And it will work.

https://godbolt.org/z/MxxdG7vbE

Cleiton

Comment: If you uncomment the lines with sub_multiplies it does not work and it is strange, the addition is wrong again.

Comment: What do you think? @Cleiton

Comment: It does... I added some comments to isolate the problem https://godbolt.org/z/sPPMcM4rE, GCC is not instantiating with the correct *value* parameter

Comment: So this is a bug in GCC? @Cleiton

Comment: I think it might, CPPInsight got it correctly  `template<>
Polynomial<double, 1> add<&<template param Polynomial<double, 1>{{{-1.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00}}}>, &<template param Polynomial<double, 1>{{{-1.000000e+00, 8.000000e+00}}}> >()`  but CPPInsight uses only Clang

Comment: Yes, I know that clang gives the correct result. But I wasn't sure if it is a bug in GCC or I had a bug in my code. @Cleiton